# GTK# использование DrawingArea

Tags: c#, gtk, рисование, cairo

Хочу написать змейку на GTK#, но уже несколько дней не могу разобраться с DrawingArea. Во всех примерах, что я находил, нужно подписываться на событие `drawingArea.ExposeEvent`, создавать подобный метод:

```
void OnDrawingAreaExposed (object source, ExposeEventArgs args)
    {   
        DrawingArea area = (DrawingArea) source;
        Cairo.Context ctx = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create (area.GdkWindow);

        //Что-то рисуем 

        ((IDisposable) ctx.Target).Dispose();
        ((IDisposable) ctx).Dispose ();
    }
```

Но у меня нет ни события `.ExposeEvent` у объекта `DrawingArea`, ни типа данных `ExposeEventArgs`.
Даже не знаю, с чем это связано. Хотелось бы разобраться с отрисовкой, возможно даже другими способами, например, формировать растровую картинку и сразу присваивать её какому-то аналогу `pictureBox` из winForms.

Comment: Почему GTK? Вы под Windows пишете?

Comment: @aepot, под линукс, но хотелось бы, чтоб и на винде работало. Поэтому GTK

Comment: Есть такой UI движок от Microsoft - .NET MAUI, у него нет официальной поддержки Linux, но насколько мне известно, она реализована сообществом на базе того же GTK#. Поизучайте, с большой вероятностью, вам не придется воевать с GTK самостоятельно. Технология свежая и сырая, но попробовать однозначно стоит, всё лучше, чем выдумывать самому.

Comment: @aepot, мне кажется, что у GTK больше сообщество, и проще будет найти решение. Да и к тому же начинал писать этот проект как раз чтоб лучше изучить GTK. 
К тому же для GTK на линуксе есть Glade, позволяющий легко создавать сложный интерфейс, а с MAUI на линуксе придётся ручками возиться с XAML.
Так же GTK и Qt приложения смотрятся более органично на линуксе, и не уверен, что MAUI будет так же декорироваться, чтоб вписываться в стиль системы

Comment: Не вижу ничего позорного в XAML, и опять же там можно использовать паттерн MVU, то есть вообще без XAML, типа аналог как пилят UI на базе веб-приложений. Код реализации под GTK# открытый, вы без проблем сможете изучить, как и что там работает. По поводу визуала не знаю, но стиль под Win 11 вполне тоже прилично смотрится. В любом случае, лучше 1 раз увидеть. Я сам под линуксы не пишу, поэтому что вижу - то и предлагаю. Лучше взглянуть на готовый или почти готовый инструмент, а потом решить, выбросить или использовать его.

Comment: Если вам нужно именно разобраться с GTK#, то лучше этот вопрос запостить на английском StackOverflow, так как здесь под GTK# никто ничего не пишет на шарпе, насколько мне известно, шанс получить экспертную помощь критически мал.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
`DrawArea` в приложении заменил на `Gtk.Image` и по таймеру вызываю метод `Draw`, в котором формирую изображение и присваиваю его объекту `Gtk.Image` (`img.FromSurface`).

```cs
private void Draw(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            var cs = new Cairo.ImageSurface(Format.Argb32, 500, 500);

            Cairo.Context cc = new Cairo.Context(cs);
            Cairo.PointD point1 = new Cairo.PointD(85, 0);
            Cairo.PointD point2 = new Cairo.PointD(95, 0);

            cc.Rectangle(0, 0, 500, 500);
            cc.SetSourceRGB(1, 0.5, 0);
            cc.LineWidth = 50;
            cc.Stroke();

            cc.Rectangle(25, 25, 25, 25);
            cc.SetSourceRGB(1, 0, 0);
            cc.Fill();

            img.FromSurface = cs;

            cc.GetTarget().Dispose();
            cc.Dispose();
            cs.Dispose();
        }
```